# Pages and Numbers have generic app icon in Dock

Tags: high-sierra, numbers, pages

I have a **MacBook Pro 13" Unibody Early 2011**  running macOS 10.13.6 (the latest it will support).
I wanted to replace the HDD with a 256GB SSD so I did a fresh install to the SSD in an enclosure then ran Migration Assistant.

As far as I can see everything is working OK, but there are couple of anomalies .
The Dock icons for Pages 8.1 and Numbers 6.1 seem to be some generic app icon.

I deleted the Dock entries and ran from Launchpad, but the icons remain.
In Finder the icons in Applications look OK although not in Launchpad.

I deleted  `com.apple.dock.plist` and ran the command  `killall -KILL Dock`

How can I restore the correct icons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)  In a Finder window Go to Applications.

2)  Locate the application's icon and do a Get Info.

3)  In the top left corner of the Get Info window the correct non-generic application icon should be displayed.

4)  Select that icon using the mouse.

5)  Do an Edit->Copy on the icon in the top left corner of the window.

6)  Do an Edit->Paste on the icon in the top left corner of the window.

7)  You may have to provide an administrator password.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment. I'm on Big Sur 11.7.4 and experiencing a similar problem except I have three apps showing as the question mark icons: Keynote, Numbers, Pages

Combining the info from posts by Milliways and Ant, I tried:

`rm ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/desktoppicture.db ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist && killall -KILL Dock`

Both files do exist before deleting them. The Dock continues to show the three question mark icons. The apps aren't even on my Mac that I can find so I don't know why the default Dock would even have them.

Answer (score 0):

Ther should be a file in `~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/`either called `desktoppicture.db` or with a garbled name .db. You can try to delete that file with `rm ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/*.db` and afterwards restart the dock with `killall Dock`. This should fix the issue, as the `com.apple.dock.plist` does not contain all the launchpad settings.

Comment: unfortunately not

Comment: There is no such file or that did not work?